# pandas time-interval ranges plotting, to plot enrollment lengths, with relative spacing and order

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am expecting a range of about 7-8 years max (the total time data which was collected over an enrollment study).

Creating a quick visual of the intervals balloons the max interval to 100+ years.

Ive posted my code and the output below: does anyone see the problem, with how I am handling dates.
Basically, I take the total range and the subject interval and convert that to days.

```
def timeplot(dt):
    # -- get time length
    dt = dt.reset_index()
    pd.to_datetime( dt['realtime'] )
    #print dt.dtypes #print( dt.head(1) )

    grpt = dt.groupby('subject_id')['realtime']
    # -- timestamps min, max
    subj_min  = grpt.min() ; subj_max  =  grpt.max() ;descr = grpt.describe() 

    # -- time range to ints
    # no. of days between (int)
    mn = subj_max - subj_min
    intdy = mn.map(lambda x: int(x.days))
    #intsj = subj_min.map(lambda x: int(x.days))

    #print('#deltaT', mn)
    #print('days ', mn.map(type) ) 
    print('day as int**: ', intdy )

    # -- y is number of subjects, 
    y = xrange( dt.subject_id.nunique() )
    # -- x is days int 
    mmin = dt.realtime.min() 
    mmax = dt.realtime.max()
    mlen = mmax - mmin; 
    totdys = int(mlen.days)

    # [mmin ..  (min ..  x1/2 .. max) .. mmax]
    subrange = subj_min - mmin
    subrdays = subrange.map(lambda x: int(x.days) )
    #print('##! ', len(subrdays), subrdays[:10]) 
    x5 = subrdays + intdy/2
    print( '## ', totdys, len(y), len(x5) )

    # plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.errorbar( x5, y, xerr=(intdy*10), fmt='ok', ecolor='grey',elinewidth=50, alpha=0.9)
    ax.set_xlabel("days");ax.set_ylabel("subjects")
```

for some reason the errorbar is vertical as well (guess thats just a scaling issue..)
I was trying to make my plot look more like the one below it.

** er, exactness doesnt matter, simply seeking relative order and spacing and length for visual heuristic.  As a quick hack, can the x-axis be overwritten (labeled to years)?  My attempt to scale the bar made it vertical though...

[image]

Comment: It would help if you provide a working example including sample data.